# Is it possible to crop videos and save them in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video, video-player

I'll explain my situation : I have a UI image, of fixed size, and if clicked it shows a video (like Live Photos). The video could be of every possible resolution and with an AspectRatioFitter and a mask I make the video fill the entire image. In this way only a portion of the video (that match the image resolution) is visible, the rest of it is "cropped", hides. I was wondering if it's possible to actually save to the disk only the visible section of the video, cropping the parts not visible. In the end the goal would be to have the image and the video of the same resolution. Is it possible to do this in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# to get video files on your system and crop them at your preferred times and then save them to your preferred folder. I have linked a google search for you that should help you find what you're looking for, try using the videos if you need something visual. [Crop a video using C#](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS817US817&ei=YAHrW6ShA7Cl_QaT7KWoBw&q=crop+a+video+using+c%23&oq=crop+a+video+using+c%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l2.1586.7113..7395...1.0..0.88.1321.22......0....1..gws-wiz.......0j0i71j0i131j0i67j0i13j33i22i29i30.hRZKIV15IS4)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I didn't find anything that could help me. At the moment I accomplished to implement the configuration explained, however I don't seem to find a way to actually save the video played by the Unity Video Player to the disk.